# Optics viewing angle and distance

Tags: optics, design

Almost all optics like microscope, telescope.. require observer putting their eyes very close to the optics to see.

Can the same optics designed so observer can see like viewing TV screen, i.e. from a larger distance like 30cm from optics? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few laws of optics that come into play here.  Probably the most significant one is simply this: if you step back 30 cm from the exit aperture, the aperture now subtends a very small angular field of view. Since all the light coming from the telescope must pass through that aperture, it can't take up a large part of the space your eye can see! (There are additional optics laws -- look up terms like "exit pupil" and "angular magnification" -- which explain why moving even a cm away makes the image look tiny inside the eyepiece)

Now, by comparison, if you look at the optics of a projector, that lens is designed to produce an image at some distance.  You, the viewer, can look at the entire image on the screen because it takes up a large part of your field of view.  But if you were standing at the image screen, looking at the projector, all you would be able to see is that small piece of the image which hits your eyeball.